# Net::OpenTimeout execution expired - ruby development emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making an email feature in with rails, letter opener, and some ruby service objects. The email functionality was working fine a couple days ago, but now I am getting a `Net::OpenTimeout (execution expired):` error.

here's my development.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false
```

gemfile

```
gem "letter_opener", :group => :development
```

after the email is 'sent', I check in my console and see

```
ReportCardMailer#report_card_to: processed outbound mail in 37.5ms

Sent mail to email (30006.4ms)
Date: Fri, 22 Jan 2016 16:29:49 -0800
From: reports@company_name.com
To: user_email@gmail.com
Message-ID: <56a2c97de0163_48f43ff30f1568e0200d8@MacBook-Pro-2.local.mail>
Subject: Test
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

so it appears it's sending emails, but for some reason, it's timing out before I can see it which leaves me with the error;

```
Net::OpenTimeout in CurriculumsController#edit_all
execution expired
```

if anyone has had this same error relating to emails in rails, I would love to hear any suggestions you might have about how to fix this

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @NikhilGopinath this was from me accidentally deleting the `temp` folder letter opener makes for you. my solution was to re-install letter opener and it worked. on another project, where the same thing happened, I just installed `mail_catcher` instead and it worked fine. I think `mail_catcher` is more flexible than letter opener.